# Tarjan's lowest common ancestor algorithm explanation

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am having a tough time understanding Tarjan's lowest common ancestor algorithm. Can somebody explain it with an example?

I am stuck after the DFS search, what exactly does the algorithm do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My explanation will be based on the wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_lowest_common_ancestors_algorithm) posted above :).

I assumed that you already know about the union disjoint structure using in the algorithm.
(If not please read about it, you can find it in "Introduction to Algorithm").

The basic idea is every times the algorithm visit a node `x`, the ancestor of all its descendants will be that node `x`.

So to find a Least common ancestor (LCA) `r` of two nodes `(u,v)`, there will be two cases:

- Node `u` is a child of node `v` (vice versa), this case is obvious.
- Node `u` is ith branch and `v` is the jth branch (i < j) of node `r`, so after visit node `u`, the algorithm backtrack to node `r`, which is the ancestor of the two nodes, mark the ancestor of node `u` as `r` and go to visit node `v`.
  At the moment it visit node `v`, as `u` is already marked as visited (black), so the answer will be `r`. Hope you get it!

Comment: When you find node `u`, how do you know node `r` is the ancestor of node `u` and node `v`?  Does not make sense to me how you know where to backtrack to find node `r`.

Comment: @lololololol Do you know about union disjoint structure? The algorithm is based on that.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain using the code from [CP-Algorithms](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/lca_tarjan.html):

```cpp
void dfs(int v)
{
    visited[v] = true;
    ancestor[v] = v;
    for (int u : adj[v]) {
        if (!visited[u]) {
            dfs(u);
            union_sets(v, u);
            ancestor[find_set(v)] = v;
        }
    }
    for (int other_node : queries[v]) {
        if (visited[other_node])
            cout << "LCA of " << v << " and " << other_node
                 << " is " << ancestor[find_set(other_node)] << ".\n";
    }
}
```

Let's outline a proof of the algorithm.

**Lemma 1:** For each vertex v and its parent p, after we visit v from p and union v with p, p and all vertices in the subtree of root v (i.e. p and all descendents of v, including v) will be in one disjoint set represented by p (i.e. ancester[root of the disjoint set] is p).

**Proof:** Suppose the tree has height h. Then proceed by induction in vertex height, starting from the leaf nodes.

**Lemma 2:** For each vertex v, right before we mark it as visited, the following statements are true:

1. Each v's parents pi will be in a disjoint set that contains precisely pi and all vertices in the subtrees of pi that pi has already finished visiting.
2. Every visited vertex so far is in one of these disjoint sets.

**Proof:** We proceed by induction. The statement is vacuously true for the root (the only vertex with height 0) as it has no parent. Now suppose the statement holds for every vertex of height k for k ≥ 0, and suppose v is a vertex of height k + 1. Let p be v's parent. Before p visits v, suppose it has already visited its children c1, c2, ..., cn. By Lemma 1, p and all vertices in the subtrees of root c1, c2, ..., cn are in one disjoint set represented by p. Furthermore, all newly visited vertices after we visited p are the vertices in this disjoint set. Since p is of height k, we can use the induction hypothesis to conclude that v indeed satisfies 1 and 2.

We are now ready to prove the algorithm.

**Claim:** For each query (u,v), the algorithm outputs the lowest common ancester of u and v.

**Proof:** Without loss of generality suppose we visit u before we visit v in the DFS. Then either v is a descendent of u or not.

If v is a descedent of u, by Lemma 1 we know that u and v are in one disjoint set that is represented by u, which means ancestor[find_set(v)] is u, the correct answer.

If v is not a descendent of u, then by Lemma 2 we know that u must be in one of the disjoint sets, each of them represented by a parent of v at the time we mark v. Let p be the representing vertex of the disjoint set u is in. By Lemma 2 we know p is a parent of v, and u is in a visited subtree of p and therefore a descendent of p. These are not changed after we have visited all v's children, so p is indeed a common ancestor of u and v. To see p is the lowest common ancestor, suppose q is the child of p of which v is a descendent (i.e. if we travel back to root from v, q is the last parent before we reach p; q can be v). Suppose for contradiction that u is also a descendent of q. Then by Lemma 2 u is in both the disjoint set represented by p and the disjoint set represented by q, so this disjoint set contains two v's parents, a contradiction.